# Unable to connect Redis Client if I changed the IP and port in redis conf file

Tags: redis, redis-cli

If I changed the IP from 127.0.0.1 to my Local IP in redis.conf file and I starts the redis client(redis-cli.exe), It's giving a blanck screen.[Redis-client console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvmLm.png)

Can any one please tell me the solution, how to strat redis-client in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redis-cli uses `127.0.0.1:6379` as a default address to connect. Since you changed this address, add `-h <newip>` to your redis-cli call.
Like `E:\work\Redis\redis-cli.exe -h 192.168.1.1`